# Задача по С++. Банковские проценты

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
    int x, p, y;
    cin >> x >> p >> y;
    int i = 0;

    while (x < y) {
    x = x+(x * p / 100);
    i++;
    }
    cout << i;
    }
```

Comment: И что вы хотели этим сказать?

Comment: Хорошая задача. А вот решение не очень хорошее.

Comment: Мне нужно добиться что бы программа работала быстрее

Comment: Во-первых, вы это в вопросе не указали. Во-вторых, "*Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.*". Так что, пожалуйста, исправьте свой вопрос. Заодно посмотрите это — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. И последнее — намек: наибольшее ускорение кода достигается сменой алгоритма. Кстати, для этого надо знать поставленную задачу: вдруг вы просто ошиблись? (я уже вижу ошибку...) И еще — отвечая, пишите символ @ и имя того, кому пишете.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double x, p, y;
    cin >> x >> p >> y;
    cout << ceil(log(y / x) / log(1 + p / 100.)) << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Мне кажется, стоило бы расписать теорию и пояснить, в чем ошибки у ТС. Впрочем, какой вопрос - такой и ответ :)

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: Спасибо здесь говорят, нажимая на треугольник вверх слева от ответа, а добавить слово "большое" можно, нажав там же на галочку.